# Align Check Boxes CSS

Tags: css

I want to align some check boxes with labels such that the check boxes are in a vertical row to the right side and the labels are aligned with the starting edges in a vertical row on the left side.

Comment: Please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you're currently working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.row label { flex: 1; max-width: 25%; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <label>Label</label><input type="checkbox" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label>Label 2</label><input type="checkbox" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label>Label 3</label><input type="checkbox" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```css
label {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div>
        <label>Label text</label><input type="checkbox" /> 
        <label>Label text</label><input type="checkbox" /> 
        <label>Label text</label><input type="checkbox" /> 
    </div>
<form>
```

Working Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/99g95pwd/)

Answer (score 1):

Css File:

```
.badgebox
{
    opacity: 0;
}

.badgebox + .badge
{
    /* Move the check mark away when unchecked */
    text-indent: -999999px;
    /* Makes the badge's width stay the same checked and unchecked */
    width: 27px;
}

.badgebox:focus + .badge
{
    /* Set something to make the badge looks focused */
    /* This really depends on the application, in my case it was: */

    /* Adding a light border */
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px;
    /* Taking the difference out of the padding */
}

.badgebox:checked + .badge
{
    /* Move the check mark back when checked */
    text-indent: 0;
}
```

HTML File:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <br>
        <br>
        <h1>Badgebox: CSS only checkbox badge!</h1>
        <h2>Works on Bootstrap 2.3.2 and up</h2>
        <br>
        <label for="default" class="btn btn-default">Default <input type="checkbox" id="default" class="badgebox"><span class="badge">&check;</span></label>
        <label for="primary" class="btn btn-primary">Primary <input type="checkbox" id="primary" class="badgebox"><span class="badge">&check;</span></label>
        <label for="info" class="btn btn-info">Info <input type="checkbox" id="info" class="badgebox"><span class="badge">&check;</span></label>
        <label for="success" class="btn btn-success">Success <input type="checkbox" id="success" class="badgebox"><span class="badge">&check;</span></label>
        <label for="warning" class="btn btn-warning">Warning <input type="checkbox" id="warning" class="badgebox"><span class="badge">&check;</span></label>
        <label for="danger" class="btn btn-danger">Danger <input type="checkbox" id="danger" class="badgebox"><span class="badge">&check;</span></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or

Refer this Link:

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/badgebox-css-checkbox-badge